# Potential memory leak in Java, may this code lead to the memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Let say I have a Java code, which constantly runs and every minute should get an array of really heavy objects and proceed them. The following code does the job:

```java
while (true) {

    ArrayList<HeavyObject> objArr = this.getHeavyObject();
    drv.processObject(objArr);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

May this code lead to the memory leak when executing `ArrayList<HeavyObject> objArr = this.getHeavyObject();` without assigning `objArr = null` before getting new batch of heavy objects?

According to the «[Memory leaks in Java](http://coderevisited.com/memory-leaks-in-java/)» article it's important to use assigning to `null` if I don't leave the scope of the variable (this code is a part of the `main()` and is alive until I exit the program).

Can you clarify this aspect as applied to the code listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no leaks in your code as long as the `drv` object does not maintain references to `objArr`. The reference `objArr` to your "heavy object" is limited to the scope of the while loop, and thus once you leave an iteration, it is eligible for garbage collection. 
However, if `drv` maintains a permanent reference to the object, then it will not be collected as long as the reference persists.

The example in the link you mention is when the reference to your data lives outside the scope (in their example, the `E[]` array field of the `Stack` class) and cannot be collected.

Answer (score 1):

It does make a difference.

Normally it doesn't matter if you set it to null or to some other value. Reassigning `objArr` reduces the reference count and makes it possible to GC the array.

If, however, the array is so big that you cannot fit two of them in memory at the same time, then it might help, because if you set the reference to null before the call, then the current array can be GC:ed before assigning memory for the next array.

Comment: That what I though but the example in the article, where author claims that without `array[N] = null;` the memory will leak confused me, why in my code it's OK but in his example it does the problem? Is it because `pop()` just returns element but doesn't perform anything with the array and it's element assignment?

Comment: His example is equivalent to you keeping a reference to older arrays. When an object is popped from a stack, the stack should not keep a reference to the object, hence `array[N] = null;`. The difference is that he doesn't have any new value (until someone calls `push`), that's why his code assigns `null`.